# Refresh Partial View to reload viewbag dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery

I am working on a program where I have two partial views on a page.

**MY Expectations.**

The first partial View allows me to add School Name and School Location.
The second partial View allows me to add Staff to a Particular School and their address.

So to visualize this, I add

Gardens Primary | South Beach

Savanah High  | North Side

To partial 1

In Table B, I can select a school from the dropdown list, add a staff and add a location.

**Current Situation / Problem**

The current problem I am experiencing right now is, when I add the two schools my drop down for the second partial view is blank, This make sense to me, because the viewbag wasn't refreshed, or reloaded so it has no idea of the new values.

**What I have tried**

In my attempt to accomplish this I added the following code on my "Show Modal"

```
    function ShowOutcome() {
        $('#modalOutcome').show();
        refreshOutcome();

    }
    function refreshOutcome() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Outcome", "outCome")',
            data: { "id": $('#id').val() },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
        });
}
```

The point of that code was when I open the modal to reload it using that ID.
However, when I use a breakpoint, I see the ID gets passed, everything gets called correctly, yet the partial view loads with nothing in the dropdown.

Would be grateful if I could get some assistance regarding this issue.

Controller code

```
    public ActionResult Outcome(int? id)
    {
        PENT_outCome outCome = new PENT_outCome();
        ViewBag.outPuts = new SelectList(db.Pent_outPuts.Where(x => x.psipID == id), "id", "outPuts");
        ViewBag.psipID = id;
        outCome.psipID = id;
        return PartialView(outCome);

    }
```

Comment: Your ajax request is just making a post call.  it's doing nothing with any results you may get.